# Can SiriKit pass the INSendMessageIntent to app?

Tags: ios, sirikit

Can SiriKit pass the INSendMessageIntent to my app? The intent has to be handled by my app, instead of in the Siri extension.  But the INSendMessageIntentResponseCode does not have the .continueInApp like INStartAudioCallIntentResponseCode.  There is .failureRequiringAppLaunch, but that behavior is not the preferred one.  Any idea?

Comment: I just posted a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38537721/launch-app-from-inextension-in-sirikit)

Comment: Just checked the beta 3.  There's still no .continueInApp for send message intent.

Comment: I have one in my Xcode Beta 3. Here is the file: https://gist.github.com/tsheaff/5de71c1cf53aecb9c85dc7339fc682e2

Comment: The response codes of various intents are different.  For INSendMessageIntentResponseCode, there are unspecified, ready, inProgress, success, failure, failureRequiringAppLaunch.  I hope there could be a continueInApp in a later release.