# Launch app from INExtension in SiriKit

Tags: ios, ios-app-extension, ios10, siri, sirikit

I want to use SiriKit to start a workout. Starting the workout requires opening the main app from the app extension.

The boilerplate that Apple provides for the `INStartWorkoutIntentHandling` handler is

```
func handle(startWorkout startWorkoutIntent: INStartWorkoutIntent, completion: (INStartWorkoutIntentResponse) -> Void) {
    let userActivity = NSUserActivity(activityType: NSStringFromClass(INStartWorkoutIntent))
    let response = INStartWorkoutIntentResponse(code: .success, userActivity: userActivity)
    completion(response)
}
```

How can I open my own app from here? Something like `myapp://workout?action=start&name=pushups`  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24356314/openurl-from-app-extension) doesn't seem relevant, as I don't have a `UIViewController` with a `extensionContext` property for this extension type.

Last related bit: For the other actions (pause, end) I’d prefer to not open the main app, but to simply pause the workout which is running in the main app. I could use a similar custom URL to pause it, but that would open up the app which is an extra unnecessary step. Any good way to tell the main app to take a specific action from the INExtension without opening the app?

Comment: Apple has defined [`failureRequiringAppLaunch`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/intents/instartworkoutintentresponsecode) response code, which almost implies that this is not a valid use-case from Apple's perspective. Seems unreasonable to require the app extension to re-implement the core use-case of my app (e.g. workouts involve more than just audio). I'd like to have users able to say "Siri, start a 10 minute upper body workout from MY-APP" using my custom vocabulary, and it would just start the workout in the app.

Answer (score 3):

For me I was able to launch app like so:

```
let activity  = NSUserActivity(activityType: NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb)
activity.webpageURL = URL(string: "https://mywebsite/...")        
completion(MyIntentResponse(code: .continueInApp, userActivity: activity))
```

Then this will get called in the AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    if userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb {
        if let url = userActivity.webpageURL {
            handleDeeplink(url)
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For posterity: turns out this was a phase-in of this functionality between Xcode 8 betas, it's been resolved in Xcode 8 beta 3. They added the `.continueInApp` code to `INStartWorkoutIntentResponseCode` in this version , but it wasn't there in Xcode 8 beta 2. This status code allows for the direct passing of NSUserActivity (no need to use a URL scheme).

Comment: By the way, if you intention is to have the user select the app, you don't need to go to the app to start. you can do it through Siri

Comment: Ended up doing .continueInApp because I want to show the workout with my ads

Comment: what to do if i want to open app from RideIntentExtension Handler ? I cant find .continueInApp type in rideIntentExtension

Comment: @AshishPisey Did you find a way to open main app without using continueInApp?